# Rotating Trimesh mesh plane object

Tags: python, trimesh

I'm starting to work with trimesh objects and i haven't been able to find good info on how to apply transformations to mesh objects (specifically,rotations).

I have a simple planar mesh object:

`plane = trimesh.creation.box(extents=[20, 20, 0.01])`

How can i rotate it -for example- over an axis?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this module](https://github.com/mikedh/trimesh/blob/main/trimesh/transformations.py) and especially at [this function](https://github.com/mikedh/trimesh/blob/52fded0ada210358dacef8a8b1de82d71615ade6/trimesh/transformations.py#L311).

The `rotation_matrix` requires the direction, angle and center of rotation (optional) as arguments to return the rotation matrix. Then, you can rotate your mesh by using the `apply_transform` method which requires the `rotation_matrix` as argument.

Here is the code:

```py
import math
from trimesh import creation, transformations

plane = creation.box(extents=[20, 20, 0.01])

angle = math.pi / 4
direction = [1, 0, 0]
center = [0, 0, 0]

rot_matrix = transformations.rotation_matrix(angle, direction, center)

plane.apply_transform(rot_matrix)
```